# Clustering Formulas for Networks

Tags: graphs, clustering

Consider an undirected, unweighted graph =(,). I want to compute the clustering coefficient of each node. In the publicly available [lecture from stanford](http://%5Bhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IS7UhNMQ3U&list=PLoROMvodv4rPLKxIpqhjhPgdQy7imNkDn&index=4%5D(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IS7UhNMQ3U&list=PLoROMvodv4rPLKxIpqhjhPgdQy7imNkDn&index=4)), the following formula for computing the clustering coefficient $e_v$  for a node $v$ is given as:

$$e_v = \frac {\#\text{edges among neighboring nodes}} {\#\text {node pairs among } k_v \text {neighboring nodes}} = \frac {\#\text{edges among neighboring nodes}}{{k_v \choose 2}} \in [0,1]$$

while in the documentation of the library networkX for python, defines the clustering coefficient as follows:

$$c_u = \frac {2T(u)} {deg(u) (deg(u)-1)}$$

where $T(u)$ is the number of triangles through node $u$ and $()$ is the degree of $$.

I calculated a few examples (Erdös-Renyi Networks) and both gave the same result for every node in the example graphs. Can somebody give me the intuition behind that observation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $\#\text{edges among neighboring nodes}$ is the same as $T(v)$ since a triangle through $v$ means that the side opposite to $v$ in the triangle is incident on two neighboring nodes.
2. $k_{v} = deg(v)$. Therefore, ${k_v \choose 2} = \frac{k_{v}(k_{v}-1)}{2} = \frac{deg(v)(deg(v)-1)}{2}$

Therefore,
$$e_v = \frac {\#\text{edges among neighboring nodes}}{{k_v \choose 2}}  = \frac {2T(v)} {deg(v) (deg(v)-1)}$$